# Transforming Results from Rows into Columns

Tags: mysql

I have a data set that contains both common and unique values, which I am attempting to return in a useable format to allow further analyse/work to be taken based on said results.

The desired result would be to have a script that would recognise the common values such as mpan/serial_number/read_at so as to only return a single row, but also to recognise the unique values those being the read_at and identifier.

Currently my script returns a unique row based on the identifier and the value, but I would like to be able to return a unique row for the read_at date for as many identifiers and values as are held. In most cases there are only two identifiers and values, but there could be as many as five.

The issue I have is that when I try to make distinct work, it will only then return the first found result, where I am expecting a pair of results at minimum. I am also unclear as to how I could stop getting a new row and instead create the result as an additional column?

My base script which pulls everything is as below, I have tried a few variances on this, but think this would likely be the best place to start from with regards to any help you may be able to offer?

```
SELECT * 
FROM consumer.stg_d0010_v2_026_027
/*LEFT JOIN consumer.stg_d0010_v2_026_028_029 
ON consumer.stg_d0010_v2_026_028_029.file_identifier = consumer.stg_d0010_v2_026_027.file_identifier 
AND consumer.stg_d0010_v2_026_028_029.mpan = consumer.stg_d0010_v2_026_027.mpan*/

LEFT JOIN consumer.stg_d0010_v2_026_028_030_032
ON consumer.stg_d0010_v2_026_028_030_032.file_identifier = consumer.stg_d0010_v2_026_027.file_identifier 
AND consumer.stg_d0010_v2_026_028_030_032.mpan = consumer.stg_d0010_v2_026_027.mpan

LEFT JOIN consumer.stg_d0010_v2_026_028_030_033
ON consumer.stg_d0010_v2_026_028_030_033.file_identifier = consumer.stg_d0010_v2_026_027.file_identifier 
AND consumer.stg_d0010_v2_026_028_030_033.mpan = consumer.stg_d0010_v2_026_027.mpan

where consumer.stg_d0010_v2_026_028_030_032.read_At > '2022-10-01'
and consumer.stg_d0010_v2_026_027.mpan in (

)
```

Example dataset in image below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vj1yn.png)

And desired outcome

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sVef.png)

The issue I have is that when I try to make distinct work, it will only then return the first found result, where I am expecting a pair of results at minimum. I am also unclear as to how I could stop getting a new row and instead create the result as an additional column?

Comment: TEXT rather than images is more useful when publishing sample data. BUT I can't see anything in the data which would allow you to associate an 02 value with an 01 value bearing in mind that data is not stored in any order..

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.